# GWT SelectBox ChangeHandler event doesn't work

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.5, gwt-2.8

Sample:

```
private Widget getSelectBox() {
  HorizontalPanel hPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
  hPanel.setSpacing(20);
  final ListBox dropBox = new ListBox(false);
  String[] listTypes = {"1", "2", "3"};
  for (int i = 0; i < listTypes.length; i++) {
    dropBox.addItem(listTypes[i]);
  }
  dropBox.ensureDebugId("cwListBox-dropBox");
  dropBox.getElement().setId("cms-dropBox");
  VerticalPanel dropBoxPanel = new VerticalPanel();
  dropBoxPanel.setSpacing(4);
  dropBoxPanel.add(dropBox);
  hPanel.add(dropBoxPanel);
  dropBox.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {
    public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
      Window.alert("change fired");
      dropBox.addItem("else");
      consoleLog("selected: "+ dropBox.getSelectedIndex());
    }
  });  
  return hPanel;
}
```

ChangeHandler isn't working. Although in the official example it works fine 
(http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwListBox
). But it isn't working in this code. There are no errors.

```
DOM.sinkEvents((com.google.gwt.user.client.Element) dropBox.getElement(), Event.ONCHANGE );
DOM.setEventListener((com.google.gwt.user.client.Element) dropBox.getElement(), new EventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
        if (DOM.eventGetType(event) == Event.ONCHANGE) {
              Window.alert("change fired");
              dropBox.addItem("who");
              consoleLog("selected: "+ dropBox.getSelectedIndex());                                        
        }                                             
    }
});
```

This way doesn't work neither.

upd: all works in MainEntryPoint class, but need panel.add(new SomeClass().getWidget()), and this isn't work

Comment: Well, I've just tested your first example and it works fine (an alert box appears and an 'else' option is added). I've just commented out the `consoleLog` call. Are you sure there are no errors in both GWT and browser console?

Comment: hi! well, Yes, it should work on documentation, so my brain explodes - I'm in the app it does not give any errors and not work so like if addChangeHandler is absent. so I don't even know how to track down the problem. consoleLog is just "    native void consoleLog( String text)
    /*-{
        console.log(text);
    }-*/;   "

Comment: all works in MainEntryPoint class, but panel.add(new SomeClass().getWidget()) need, and this isn't work

Comment: implements someGwtEvent for someclass needed maybe?

Comment: `new SomeClass().getWidget()` - is this necessary? If SomeClass extends `Composite` than you can just `panel.add(new SomeClass())`. Can you provide minimal code for the class containing `getSelectBox()` method?

Comment: i will try to explain in a nutshell. for example: a object "the box". in this class, we have selector: round box or square box. and depending on the choice from the bottom should be another table with options of round or square boxes. such objects assume several. "the box", "the jar", and so on. so, as i see it - just the solution for individual objects. and listener must work. i was surprised when i found they don't work

Comment: my code is exactly the same as in the documentation [link](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwListBox), but the difference is that we need the job of a listener in a separate class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason for not working eventListener: inattention.

don't override html content of ready DOM like  `container.getElement().setInnerHTML(container.getElement().getInnerHTML()+"<div>somehtml</div>");` after adding any widget with a eventListener

Answer (score 0):

So, you just need to hook up a ListBox `ChangeEvent` from another class. You can do this in a lot of ways. Here are two easy methods.

Let's assume that a ListBox is defined in `class A` and you need a handler in `class B`.

- First method: expose a ListBox from `class A` and use it in `class B` to set up handler.
- Second method: add a public method in `class A` that sets a handler on a ListBox, this will be used in `class B`.

You will need to pass an instance of `class A` to the constructor of `class B`.

---

```
public class A {
    private ListBox dropBox;

    public A() {
        // constructor - set up dropBox
        ...
    }

    // first method - expose a dropBox
    public ListBox getDropBox() {
        return dropBox;
    }

    // second method - allow external handlers
    public HandlerRegistration addListBoxChangeHandler(ChangeHandler handler) {
        return dropBox.addChangeHandler(handler);
    }
}

public class B {
    private A instanceOfClassA;

    public B(A instanceOfClassA) {
        // constructor
        this.instanceOfClassA = instanceOfClassA;
        ...

        // first method - dropBox is exposed in class A
        instanceOfClassA.getDropBox().addChangeHandler(handler);

        // second method - add external handler
        instanceOfClassA.addListBoxChangeHandler(handler);
    }
}
```

The second method is more elegant.

Comment: `private Widget getBox() {
    HorizontalPanel hPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
    MainEntryPoint.dropBox = new ListBox();
    String[] lTypes = {"R", "S"};
    for (String s : lTypes) MainEntryPoint.dropBox.addItem(s);
    VerticalPanel dropBoxPanel = new VerticalPanel();
    dropBoxPanel.add(MainEntryPoint.dropBox);  
    hPanel.add(dropBoxPanel);
    MainEntryPoint.addListBoxChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {
      public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
          Window.alert("fired");
      }
    }); 
    return hPanel;
  }`

Comment: if i understand right, in the first method, we determine the listbox and create the register of the event. here is the code. it didn't work, unfortunately. the second method is not very suitable, because the constructor of the selector must be in the class of the object

Comment: i think that, most likely, the right direction is the implementation like `public class SomeObject implements SomeHandler { }`,  this is done in the examples of library, but the examples are too large, i'm a novice for a GWT, therefore ask here for a simple example. keep looking

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the additional code. It looks suspicious.  For example what is the type of`MainEntryPoint.dropBox`? Initializing this field from another class seems like a bad design and could possible point to the problem or in some other way to the problem.

Comment: guys, the thing is that the eventHandlers in a new test project works fine for widgets, which are assembled by in a different classes, without any of the implements or extends. the question here, most likely the following: under what circumstances the eventHandlers may not be registered

Comment: @Hilbrand Bouwkamp, MainEntryPoint.dropBox in this case is a just `public static ListBox dropBox;` field in main class

Comment: guys i'm sorry for this complicated question. i override html content of fragment (`container.getElement().setInnerHTML(container.getElement().getInnerHTML()+"<div>somehtml</div>");`) after `.add(widget);`, wherein eventListeners has been reset. i promise what i'll be more careful in the future